# Is it possible for a java web applet to grab its own URL and parse it?

Tags: java, japplet

I was wondering if it would be possible for a Java Web Applet to grab its own URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Applet#getCodeBase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getCodeBase%28%29)

Comment: Or [getDocumentBase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getDocumentBase%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Think this help u.
[Java URL example - A Java class to download and parse URL contents](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/java-program-download-parse-contents-of-url)